# puppet regsubst multiple substitutions

Tags: ruby, regex, puppet

I need to swap the last digit in `$name` from 1 to 2 or 2 to 1

In Ruby (irb) I have got it working like this

```
irb(main):038:0> name = "drdev-ams-1"
irb(main):059:0> name = name.sub(/[12]$/, '1' => 2, '2' => 1)
=> "drdev-ams-2"
irb(main):060:0> name = name.sub(/[12]$/, '1' => 2, '2' => 1)
=> "my_string-1"
```

How is the same achieved in puppet 2.7?

```
regsubst($name, '[12]$', "'1' => 2, '2' => 1")
```

This does not give the correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby this code

```
{ '1' => 2, '2' => 1 }
```

defines a [hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html) that in your case is used by the sub method to replace any search result that is equal to one of the keys of this hash with the value of that key. In Ruby the braces can be omitted when a hash is the last parameter of a function call. The following two calls are equivalent:

```
name.sub(/[12]$/, '1' => 2, '2' => 1)
name.sub(/[12]$/, { '1' => 2, '2' => 1 })
```

Puppet has its own syntax for [hashes](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_datatypes.html#hashes), which is *almost* the same as Ruby's syntax not surprisingly. There are some slight differences you should be aware of.

First of all you've put double quotes around your hash. This means the Puppet parser will produce a string instead of a hash. Also, Puppet requires the braces even if the hash is the last parameter of a function call. Lastly, Puppet does not need quotes around the hash keys (although it doesn't matter if you supply them). It doesn't work the other way around though: in Ruby `{ hello => 'world' }` results in a parse error, while the Puppet parser understands this just fine.

Equipped with the understanding between the two hashes your Puppet code just needed a bit of tweaking:

```
regsubst($name, '[12]$', { '1' => 2, '2' => 1 } )
```

Here is the proof this works:

```
$x1 = "drdev-ams-1"
$x2 = "drdev-ams-2"
alert( "x1 = ${x1}" )
alert( "x2 = ${x2}" )
$y1 = regsubst($x1, '[12]$', { '1' => 2, '2' => 1 } )
$y2 = regsubst($x2, '[12]$', { '1' => 2, '2' => 1 } )
alert( "y1 = ${y1}" )
alert( "y2 = ${y2}" )
```

Produces the following output:

```
Alert: Scope(Class[main]): x1 = drdev-ams-1
Alert: Scope(Class[main]): x2 = drdev-ams-2
Alert: Scope(Class[main]): y1 = drdev-ams-2
Alert: Scope(Class[main]): y2 = drdev-ams-1
```

Hope this helps.

I'm from Amsterdam too by the way.